# Custom Navigation Drawer : The ListView over the Toolbar

Tags: android, listview, layout, navigation-drawer

I have this MainActivity.xml and I would like when my ListView (Drawer Navigation) opens over the ToolBar.

A change in my XML is enough to get a result ?
If it's possible with ToolBar and style.

```html
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="305dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```html
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the root LinearLayouta move the toolbar inside the drawerlayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I changed my main layout for <FrameLayout> (instead of <LinearLayout>) but I lose the click on the Toolbar. Making slider menu appears and works well over the Toolbar.

Comment: you mean the click on the burger menu ?

Comment: When I use a FrameLayout I can't use the click on the toolbar to open the NavigationDrawer. But I can do the slider from left to right. The order of the layouts can't be correct ?

Comment: no, i made a mistake, toolbar need to be around the content frame, I edit